# Fast import of csv file into access database via VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, csv

I am having problems getting the speed that I want in importing approx 30,000 lines of data from Tab separated files in to an Access database. The File import is managed from a VB.net 2010 program that I have written.

The program is currently looping through each line and issuing a SQL insert statement for each one. However this is taking about 2 hours to complete. If I manually import in the same file directly into access using Get External Data, it takes about 30 seconds.

I was thinking that I might be able to create a datagridview linked to MS access and somehow run a native .net command to import the file into the datagridview and then quickly write the data to access but i'm not sure if this is possible.

By the way doing a manual import is not an option, it needs to go through the vb.net application for various reasons.

Can any one provide any suggestions on how I might speed things up?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Well, without seeing anything of what you have done so far, it's very difficult to help. Please post the loop code.

Answer (score 2):

You can run an SQL statement against your MS Access connection to import text/csv. To import into a new table:

```vb
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT F1 AS id, F2 AS firstname " &
    "INTO MyNewTable " &
    "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=No;CharacterSet=850;DATABASE=C:\__tmp].table1.csv;"
```

To import into an existing table:

```vb
cmd.CommandText =
    "INSERT INTO MyExistingTable " &
    "SELECT F1 AS id, F2 AS firstname " &
    "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=No;CharacterSet=850;DATABASE=C:\__tmp].table1.csv;"
```

You can also use a schema.ini file for non-standard delimiters. ( [Exporting data into a pre-formatted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255004/exporting-data-into-a-preformatted-file/13255522#13255522) , [Create comma separated file (csv) from access - scheduled daily from windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482242/create-comma-separated-file-csv-from-access-scheduled-daily-from-windows/13483597#13483597))

Comment: @gordonthompson In my opinion, that was too substantial a change.

Comment: Fair enough. Using a [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx) file is better than an HKLM registry tweak, for sure.

Answer (score -1):

The question is why use .Net at all? If your using a newer version of Access it will run full on SQL.  This allows you to use SQL [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).  Bulk insert blows the pants off every other method of data insertion in SQL.

If you need to manipulate the data you can bulk insert the raw data in a heap table (just a raw dump of the data from the file) then use SQL to update/move the relevant data into the correct table(s).

Comment: I am writing an application for users who will not be very good with computers/software. As I wont be there when they will be using the software, I need to put everything in one nice easy to use front end, with all the hard work done for them in the code. I also need to process the data once it has been imported, doing it all through VB allows the user to do everything in one click.

Comment: Its fine to manage the import though .Net but SQL's main purpose in life is handle large chunks of data very efficiently.  If you take some time to learn SQL's abilities you'll most likely discover you can do 90% of your prepossessing within stored procedures and T-SQL.

Comment: Access SQL is still very different from T-SQL. Access SQL does not support `BULK INSERT`.