# Create comma separated file (csv) from access - scheduled daily from windows

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

I would like to create a vbs file to export an access table in a csv file (comma separated).
I saw this coda from Remou. It works, but it create tab separated. Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

```
db = "C:\Docs\LTD.mdb"
TextExportFile = "C:\Docs\Exp.txt"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open _
   "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
   "Data Source =" & db

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblMembers"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fs.CreateTextFile(TextExportFile, True)

a = rs.GetString

f.WriteLine a

f.Close
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not difficult to create a standard CSV

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=z:\Docs\test.accdb"

sSQL = "select * into " 
sSQL= sSQL & "[text;database=z:\docs\;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes].[csvfile.csv]"
sSQL= sSQL & " from table1"

cn.Execute sSQL
```

A VBScript file will run quite well from the Task Scheduler.

Edit re comments

If the decimal separator in your locale is a comma, you may run into problems. You can override the Windows locale settings with a schema.ini file, you need only include the name of the file and items you wish to change:

```
[csvfile.csv]
DecimalSymbol=.
```

A full list is available form Microsoft: [Schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx)

There is no reason why you should not write the schema.ini in your code prior to export, except be sure not to overwrite existing schemas -- you can append.

You will get information on your system locale from the windows control panel: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IE/windows7/Change-the-system-locale

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I tried, but i get the following error "Text file specification Field separator matches decimal separator or text delimiter".

Comment: Have you got a schema.ini that remaps the separator? Does your locale use a comma as the decimal separator? If it is the former, remove the file name from schema.ini, if it is the latter, you need to make a decision. CSV means comma separated value, so the comma is integral to the file. Your choices are to remap the decimal separator to stop (.) uing a schema.ini file or to quote all numbers. I recommend the first option. I can help you with this is you say which way you want to go.

Comment: Thank you! I did not work with vb, so i never created schema. I'm a PHP developer :) I think the schema.ini the best option, but where can i see, what is the default formatter? Can you show me an example schema.ini? Best Regards.