# DoCmd.TransferText into another DB, using an Import Spec in CurrentDB

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office, etl

The challenge is in the title.

How can I use `<DB>.DoCmd.TransferText...` to import a file into a separate DB, using an Import Spec in CurrentDB?

**Please don't reply if your suggestion is to create a linked table to the destination DB, or to create the import spec in the destination DB.**

Here's my code so far, but obviously it does not work because the file spec is in CurrentDB instead of the destination DB.

```
Option Compare Database

Function job1()

    Dim sFinalDB As String, sTableName As String, sSpecName As String, sFileName As String

    sFinalDB = "path\db.mdb"
    sTableName = "tblName"
    sSpecName = "specName"
    sFileName = "path\test.csv"


    fn_ImportTxt sFinalDB, sSpecName, sTableName, sFileName, True

End Function



Function fn_ImportTxt(sDBPath As String, _
    sSpecName As String, _
    sTableName As String, _
    sFileName As String, _
    bHeaders As Boolean)

    Dim acApp As Access.Application
    Set acApp = New Access.Application

    acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase sDBPath

    acApp.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, sSpecName, sTableName, sFileName, bHeaders

    acApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
    acApp.Quit acQuitSaveNone
    Set acApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: What have you got against (temporarily) creating a table link?

Comment: I already know how to do that, and I was looking for another way to reach my goal without creating any temp Access objects (in CurrentDB).

Comment: Then you must let "another db" open your "currentdb", reading the import specification there, but that would effectively be the same as if you ran it all from your current db. If you are so afraid of a temporary link, you can run a query that opens the db/table directly. But still, why make it more difficcult than necessary?

Comment: It is easy enough to use pure SQL to import a table, rather than TransferText. You may need a schema.ini file if the text file is in a non-standard format. This is an export, but you will get the general idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482242/create-comma-separated-file-csv-from-access-scheduled-daily-from-windows/13483597#13483597

Comment: @Fionnuala - thanks, this is an interesting option.

Comment: BTW you can use DAO as well as ADO. DAO is generally better with MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question today trying to do the same thing myself.
I found that the specs are stored in two system object tables "MSysIMEXColumns" and "MSysIMEXSpecs".
What I did was copying the two system object table to the destination database every time before I run the import procedure, that why the specs are also available in the destination database.

```
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", DBPath, acTable, "MSysIMEXColumns", "MSysIMEXColumns"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", DBPath, acTable, "MSysIMEXSpecs", "MSysIMEXSpecs"
    Dim NewAccessApp As Access.Application
    Set NewAccessApp = New Access.Application
    With NewAccessApp
        .OpenCurrentDatabase strDBPath, True
        .DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, ImportSpec, TabelName, FilePath, True
        .CloseCurrentDatabase
        .Quit
    End With
```

Obviously this would only work if you don't mind overwriting the spec table in the destination database.

Comment: yeah, this is what I ended up doing too. thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to answer "why not create a linked table to the destination DB". I work in an environment where ADO, DAO, ODBC, and any direct access are impossible due to network security. I can do a direct query against the remote DB using a module with the DoCmd method. If network security eliminates that, I will have to scrabble deeper, but I can import data and use a remote query to work on the data.