# can i import csv to mdb

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

the code first changes the dbf file to csv.

```
Sub FindFiles()
    Dim strDocPath As String
    Dim strCurrntFile As String
    Dim Fname As String

strDocPath = "Y:\Eilat\Shapes\"
'strCurrentFile = Dir(strDocPath & "*.*")
strCurrentFile = Dir(strDocPath & "111.dbf")

    Workbooks.Open FileName:=strDocPath & strCurrentFile
    Fname = Left$(strCurrentFile, Len(strCurrentFile) - 4) & ".csv"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=strDocPath & Fname, FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)


Dim filepath As String
Dim sqlinsert As String
Dim sqlvalue As String
Dim sqlquery As String
Dim sqlwhere As String

'Set db = CurrentDb
directory = "Y:\Eilat\Shapes\"
FileName = "111.csv" 
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & directory & ";" _
& "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & FileName
'rs.Open strSQL, strcon
'rs.MoveFirst
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim aryMyData() As String


Open directory & FileName For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)             ' Loop until end of file.
    Line Input #1, strTextLine   ' Read line into variable.
    aryMyData = Split(strTextLine, ",") 'Split text into array by comma
```

'    (the csv length changes for example this is the columns in csv but it can be longer. EHANDLE,UseCode,UseCode2,Descriptio,Gush,Helka,Owner,OwnerID,Holder,HolderID,Floor,PhysicalNo,Date,Area,Comments,Address,StreetName,HouseNo,Telephone,Fax,Email,Manager,Business,SerialNo,MeasuredBy,Height,BlockNo,Mapkey,User1,User2,user3 is the columns in csv but it can be longer.

strSQL = "??(what sql statement need??)

(dont know how to do import to  mdb "Y:\Eilat\Arnona\Eilat.mdb")

```
Debug.Print strSQL
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

Loop
Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You actuall yhave several options. You can link the csv file has a table and then just do an insert-selet or you can try building a text file and an import specification to import it that way. There's probably another couple of ways, but those are the two that stuck out to me.

Comment: I want to do it in code

Comment: Yeah, i understand that. The things i suggested are done via code. Google the things i said and learn soem cool techniques

Comment: and can i use "import specification" outside the mdb file from the code.

Comment: you really ought to look these things up dude - i found this form the first result from google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950791/docmd-transfertext-into-another-db-using-an-import-spec-in-currentdb

Answer (score 0):

With the assumptions:

- Your code properly opens the CSV file and reads line by line
- All your table fields are of type String
- Your table has fields Field_01, Field_02, Field_03 into which you
  want to import columns 1, 2 and 3 of the CSV file

You can use

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO MyTable (Field_01, Field_02, Field_03) VALUES ('" & aryMyData(0) & "','" & aryMyData(1) & "','" & aryMyData(2) & "'")
```

and expand as needed for all your fields and columns.

This is a very basic example that assumes your table is specifically prepared for the CSV file you are importing. If you expect the table's design to change to accommodate whatever CSV file you are importing that is way more complicated.