# Export Access table to delimited txt file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ms-access-2007

I need export my table from DB Access 2007 to delimited txt file with **`;`** using VBScript.

My code below:

```
   Set accDB = CreateObject("Access.Application")       
      accDB.visible = true
      accDB.automationsecurity = 1
      accDB.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\Users\db2015.mdb")        
      accDB.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, ";", "tb2015", "D:\Users\tb2015.txt", False 
      accDB.CloseCurrentDatabase
      accDB.Quit          
   Set accDB = Nothing
```

But I have error: tb2015.txt not found

I have tried add in my code this:

```
  accDB.DoCmd.OpenQuery "SelectQuery", acNormal, acEdit
  accDB.DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "tb2015", "txt", "D:\Users\tb2015.txt"
```

In this case I don't have error but the tb2015.txt is delimited with **`|`** and not with **`;`**

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit #1**

This is the new code, but I have error:

```
   Set accDB = CreateObject("Access.Application")       
      accDB.visible = true
      accDB.automationsecurity = 1
      accDB.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\Users\db2015.mdb") 
      Const acExportDelim = 2     
      accDB.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tb2015", "D:\Users\tb2015.txt", False 
      accDB.CloseCurrentDatabase
      accDB.Quit          
   Set accDB = Nothing
```

**Edit #2**

The solution is this code:

```
   Const acExportDelim = 2
   Set accDB = CreateObject("Access.Application")
      accDB.visible = true
      accDB.automationsecurity = 1
      accDB.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\Users\db2015.mdb")        
      accDB.DoCmd.OpenQuery "myView", acNormal, acEdit  
      accDB.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "tb2015", "tb2015", "D:\Users\tb2015.txt"
      accDB.CloseCurrentDatabase
      accDB.Quit
   Set accDB = Nothing
```

Comment: You could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482242/create-comma-separated-file-csv-from-access-scheduled-daily-from-windows/13483597#13483597 I very much doubt that ";" is the name of your specification, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214141(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: *"but I have error"* - What error? In which line?

Comment: Sorry, I have error in line 11 `accDB.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tb2015", "D:\Users\tb2015.txt", False` the error is **for the action or method requires the subject**

Comment: Sorry, I have error in line 11 `accDB.DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tb2015", "D:\Users\tb2015.txt", False` the error is **for the action or method requires the argument** –

Comment: Solved in **Edit #2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is:

VBScript doesn't know `acExportDelim`, so it is interpreted as unknown variable, with value 0.

In the context of `DoCmd.TransferText`, 0 = `acImportDelim`.

So it tries to import tb2015.txt, and you get the "file not found" error.

Copy `Const acExportDelim = 2` from the Access Object catalog, and add it to your script. And remove the ";" SpecificationName parameter.

Note: `acOutputTable = 0`, that's why your `DoCmd.OutputTo` runs (by accident).

To avoid such errors, add [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to the top of your script, it enforces variable declaration.

Comment: Thank you for help, please see my Edit #1 in first question, the suggestion not working.