# importing CSV file encoded as UTF-8 into Access

Tags: csv, ms-access, utf-8, import, ms-access-2010

Further to an earlier question here

[Fast import of csv file into access database via VB.net 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336052/fast-import-of-csv-file-into-access-database-via-vb-net-2010)

I tried using the following code in my .NET application (VB.NET 2010)

```
cmd.CommandText =
"SELECT F1 AS id, F2 AS firstname " &
"INTO MyNewTable " &
"FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=No;CharacterSet=850;DATABASE=C:\__tmp].table1.csv;"
```

and it seemed to work, but when I opened the database in Access the table showed garbled characters.

I think maybe `CharacterSet=850` is not the correct setting for my CSV file. I tried searching for a character set list, but I couldn't find it.

My .csv file uses UTF-8. What should I use for the CharacterSet number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CharacterSet number for UTF-8 is `CharacterSet=65001`, so your CommandText should be

```vb
cmd.CommandText =
        "SELECT F1 AS id, F2 AS firstname " &
        "INTO MyNewTable " &
        "FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=No;CharacterSet=65001;DATABASE=C:\__tmp].table1.csv;"
```

Note also that this approach requires that the UTF-8 file be saved **without** a BOM (byte order mark), which is unusual for the Windows platform. (If the file does include a BOM then the first record will be imported as blank fields.)